# Philosophy as target for moving question

Tags: feature-request, closing

I voted to close [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92646/is-cantors-theorem-based-on-a-fallacy) as "off topic". The list of possible sites presented to me did not include the one I had in mind, the philosophy SE site. Having that as an option would be nice for this kind of question.

Comment: I would also like to see philosophy SE listed as an option, especially for cases where the question is a philosophy of math question or superficially related to math but better suited to that site. It feels too extreme to just select "blatantly off topic" in these cases.

Comment: +1 to this feature request. It seems like this happens often enough (posts making statements using terminology from math but with no interest in the mathematical definitions of those terms) to warrant adding philosophy SE to the list in the "belongs on another site" close reason.

Answer (score 10):

The moderators can migrate to any SE site, so in the future flag and let the moderators take care of it.